# SimpleBlobDetection Code

Tags: opencv, blob

Hi I am a pure novice in image processing especially with openCV. I want to write a program on blob detection that takes an image as an input and returns the color and centroid of the blob. My image consists purely of regular polygons in a black background. For eg. my image might consist of a green triangle(equilateral) or a red square in a black background. I want to use the simpleBlobDetection class in opencv and its 'detect' function for this purpose. Since I'm a novice a full program will be a lot of help to me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the complementary openCV library cvblob. It has an example to automatically obtain blobs in an image, centroid, contour, etc.

Here is the source code, i tried it in OSX and works really fine.
Link: https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/